# vCenter SSO without AD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, ad-lds

I have an ESXi Server with a vCenter virtual appliance image and an image of a Windows 2008 TS.

The Windows 2008 image has an external Ethernet connection configured to another network, so users can login via a terminal session and get access the virtual machines on the ESXi Host via vCenter image.

It’s all working really well, but I have one problem - SSO. I would like to control access for the vCenter via the users configured on the Windows 2008 R2 Server, but I would also like to avoid installing AD functionality on the image because I want to keep it simple and keep the Windows 2008 fast and light.

Is this possible in any way? I have tried to read up on AD LDS, but can’t figure out if that I what I am looking for?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of vSphere?

Comment: its version 5.5

Comment: What's the reason for using OS local users instead of employing your company's AD?

Comment: This is a test network, and we are completely cut-off any other networks or internet. the only connection into the network is via a RDP connection from a cooperate network to the Windows 2008 TS. We are not allowed to configure firewall to authenticate with cooperate domain (we would like to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users on your Windows VM are local, right? I think you have to install SSO on this machine. That's the only option possible to make use of local operating system users. (see [Identity Sources for vCenter Server with vCenter Single Sign-On](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-1F0106C9-0524-4583-9AC5-A748FD1DC4C5.html))

You'll have to reconfigure your VCSA to use this new SSO installation, though.

edit: [Change the vCenter Single Sign-On Mode in the VMware vCenter Server Appliance](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vcenterhost.doc/GUID-689AC3F1-6654-4EE2-A146-663BD157FDC2.html)

Comment: Thanks Mario, that actually sounds like a really good solution. I did not know that I was possible to install SSO without vCenter. I will download vCenter and see if it solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to install a domain controller virtual machine. That's what the vSphere appliance works best with, and it's the native solution for your Windows RDS server.

vSphere/vCenter is using Likewise to provide AD/LDAP integration. It expects either pure LDAP or Microsoft Active Directory. Think about the target market for *paid* vSphere; shops with Windows footprints. Anything outside of the norm isn't going to be tested as well or supported in the best manner... Soo...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would really like to avoid installing a AD service on the network.


I can see that its possible to use AD LDS as to authenticate user from eg. ASP, so I tried to setup LDAP the same way in vCenter, but I can't get it to work.

http://ramanam.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/using-ad-lds-with-asp-net-membership/

Comment: @user2536967 So... you want AD, but you don't want to use AD to get AD?

Comment: Yes, I want someway to authenticate users without a full AD setup. manually configuring user in vCenter that authenticate against windows users would be fine.

Comment: What's a "full AD setup"? Installing a role on a server? What's the problem with using a domain controller?

Comment: Sheesh. You can squeeze a DC for just a few users into 512MB of RAM. This is not a big deal, and has a lot of benefits beyond just this particular situation. Besides, how did you think people were going to sign on to Terminal Services?